# Why does Earth have two moons after the season finale?

Tags: devilman-crybaby

After the closing credits of episode 10 of *Devilman: Crybaby*, the series ends on an image of a reformed Earth with two moons.

Why does Earth have two moons at the end of Devilman: Crybaby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two moons are the two halves of the old moon split apart in the final battle.

This happened during the season finale but can also be seen in the ending credits and is alluded to in the opening. It holds symbolism for the main conflict of the show between Akira and Ryo. It also ties in with other works in the series [as mentioned by @Sn0wCrack](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/44526/31618).

[image: The moon being split in half]

Comment: The opening doesn't show any moon until the earth is destroy by God, as I showed in my answer. (**spoilers ahead again**) You could argue the opening in and of itself (being Ryo's final speech before the earth is destroyed) may be from another loop in which he and Akira fight and God steps in, as we know from the various sequels, God is punishing Ryo for his descent towards him by making him face his only friend over and over again. You can also clearly see the broken moon in the post credits sequence (the one surrounded by debris).

Comment: @Sn0wCrack Aah thanks for pointing that out, you are right, the scene in the op with the moon seems to be left open to interpretation. It *could* be split in half but it also may not be, and one would only assign the split context after watching the full anime. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The new moon seems to be a chunk of the old earth, the first episode's introduction scene where God is destroying earth we see this pretty easily illustrated.

Earth Before:

[image: Earth during God's first attack during the opening of Episode 1]

Earth After:

[image: Earth after God's first attack during the opening of Episode 1]

And since this same event occurs during the end of Devilman: Crybaby, it's safe to assume this is the cause of the second moon during the post-credits sequence.

As for a reasoning on showing this with such prevalence (**light spoilers ahead**): a lot of elements from the Devilman: Crybaby adaptation actually come from the "fleshing out" (or more accurately "hinting at") of the timelooping themes of the later Devilman Series works, namely the few Devilman "sequels", such as [Violence Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violence_Jack) and [Devilman Lady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Lady) (simply Devil Lady in English).